# Parse Push Notification for Everyone or for selective device using core java

Tags: java, parse-platform

I am using **Parse for Push Notification**.
          Finding problems with push from my java desktop application.
          My target is **Everyone** and **selected** android device.
          I tried with the code below and getting status as done Zero.
          Can anyone help me to implement this?

```
          HttpURLConnection conn;
         OutputStreamWriter wr;
         BufferedReader rd;
        JSONObject obj = null;
         String APPLICATION_ID = "";
        String REST_API_KEY = "";
        String PUSH_URL = "https://api.parse.com/1/push";
```

Might be I am not sending enough details to the server.
Below parameters are enough or more need.>

```
        String type = "android";
        Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
        data.put("alert", "push data test");
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
        jo.put("type", type);
        String[] channels = new String[] { "" };
        jo.put("channels", channels);
        jo.put("data", data);
        jo.put("title", "Hi man!!");
        jo.put("alert", "helo world!!!");
        jo.put("alert", "helo world!!!");
        String line, response;
        // HttpURLConnection is created
        URL url = new URL(PUSH_URL);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(PUSH_URL)).openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestProperty("X-Parse-Application-Id", APPLICATION_ID);
        conn.setRequestProperty("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", REST_API_KEY);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        // Sets the connection timeout of 8sec
        conn.setConnectTimeout(8000);
        wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(jo.toString());
        wr.flush();
        rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        response = "";
        line = "";
        // Read the response from the server
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            response = response + line;
        }
        wr.close();
        rd.close();
```